# Either repainting (because calc_on_order_fills=true) or my trailing stop loss in the strategy.exit is not working, Pine, Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, repaint, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

Good Morning all! I've written a strategy in the Pine Editor, but unfortunately it doesn't quite work the way I want it to. Either it comes to repainting (because calc_on_order_fills=true) or my trailing stop loss in the strategy.exit function does not work from the first candle, but only from the following one.

On top of that the strategy alert is giving an alert way too often. Is that a result of the repainting?

I already tried following:
-Using trailing stop loss calculated by the ATR instead of trail_price and trail_offset in the entry orders (didn´t change anything)
-Using the parameter (open,close,high,low) of the previous bar for calculating my entry order conditions (didn´t change anything)
-Add `strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(strategy.closedtrades) != time`
or `strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades) != bar_index` (didn´t work)

Can someone please help me with this? I would be happy about messages :)

That´s my code right now:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, calc_on_every_tick = false, calc_on_order_fills = true)


// Set exit levels with input options (optional)
LimitPerc = input.int(title="Take Profit (0,1%)", minval=0, step=1, defval=10) * 0.001
StopPerc = input.int(title="Stop Loss / Trailing Offset (0,1%)", minval=0, step=1, defval=5) * 0.001
TrailPerc = input.int(title="Trailing Offset (0,1%)", minval=0, step=1, defval=2) * 0.001

 
//Movin Averages incl Plot
//EMA
emaplot = input (true, title="Show EMA on chart")
len = input.int(minval=1, step=1, defval=9, title="ema Length")
src = close[1]
out = ta.ema(src, len)
up = out > out[1]
down = out < out[1]
mycolor = up ? color.green : down ? color.red : color.blue
plot(out and emaplot ? out :na, title="EMA", color=mycolor, linewidth=3)

//SMA
smaplot = input (true, title="Show SMA on chart")
len2 = input.int(minval=1, step=1, defval=2, title="sma Length")
src2 = close[1]
out2 = ta.sma(src2, len2)
up2 = out2 > out2[1]
down2 = out2 < out2[1]
mycolor2 = up2 ? color.green : down2 ? color.red : color.blue
plot(out2 and smaplot ? out2 :na , title="SMA", color=mycolor2, linewidth=1)


//Stochastic Momentum Index incl Plot
//Stoch RSI
a = input.int(minval=1, step=1, defval=2, title = "Percent K Length")
b = input.int(minval=1, step=1, defval=2, title = "Percent D Length")
// Range Calculation
ll = ta.lowest (low[1], a)
hh = ta.highest (high[1], a)
diff = hh - ll
rdiff = close[1] - (hh+ll)/2
// Nested Moving Average for smoother curves
avgrel = ta.ema(ta.ema(rdiff,b),b)
avgdiff = ta.ema(ta.ema(diff,b),b)
// SMI calculations
SMI = avgdiff != 0 ? (avgrel/(avgdiff/2)*100) : 0
SMIsignal = ta.ema(SMI,b)
SMIup = SMI > SMI[1]
SMIdown = SMI < SMI[1]


//Heikin Ashi
HAopen  = (open[1]+close[1])/2
HAclose = ohlc4[1]
HAhigh  = math.max (high, open, close)
HAlow   = math.min (low, open, close)
HAup    = HAopen < HAclose
HAdown  = HAopen > HAclose


//Conditions for trades
LongCondition = HAup and SMIup and up and up2 and (strategy.opentrades == 0)
ShortCondition = HAdown and SMIdown and down and down2 and (strategy.opentrades == 0)


//Submit entry orders
if (LongCondition and time>timestamp(2022, 07, 04, 07, 00))
    strategy.entry(id = "Long", direction = strategy.long, alert_message = "Place Long Order", comment = "Long Entry")


if (ShortCondition and time>timestamp(2022, 07, 04, 07, 00))
    strategy.entry(id = "Short", direction = strategy.short, alert_message = "Place Short Order", comment = "Short Entry")

// and strategy.closedtrades.entry_time(strategy.closedtrades) != time
// and strategy.closedtrades.entry_bar_index(strategy.closedtrades) != bar_index


// Determine stop loss price
longLimitPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + LimitPerc)
shortLimitPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - LimitPerc)
longStopPrice   = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - StopPerc)
shortStopPrice  = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + StopPerc)
trailingOffset  = (strategy.position_avg_price - (strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - TrailPerc))) / syminfo.mintick


//Submit exit orders
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id = "Long", alert_trailing = "Exit Long Order", trail_price = strategy.position_avg_price, trail_offset = trailingOffset, comment = "Long Exit")

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id = "Short", alert_trailing = "Exit Short Order", trail_price = strategy.position_avg_price, trail_offset = trailingOffset, comment = "Short Exit")

//END
```

Answer (score 0):

if your problem are "the strategy.exit function does not work from the first candle, but only from the following one", than remove if checks for exits:

```
//Submit exit orders
strategy.exit(id = "Long", alert_trailing = "Exit Long Order", trail_price = strategy.position_avg_price, trail_offset = trailingOffset, comment = "Long Exit")
strategy.exit(id = "Short", alert_trailing = "Exit Short Order", trail_price = strategy.position_avg_price, trail_offset = trailingOffset, comment = "Short Exit")
```